# Spring @cache not working for caching list with no parms

Tags: java, spring, caching

Hi i have a problem trying to cache a result of a function that is a list 
as i debug it first time the function is called the second the cache return nothing  an empty list
i also tried to add key="'all'" and the method name but with nothing comes back

```
@Override
@Cacheable(value = "categories" )
public List<Category> getCategories() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    LOG.info("start getCategories");
    return repository.findAll(); //
}
@Configuration
@EnableCaching
public class CachingConfig implements CachingConfigurer {
@Bean(destroyMethod="shutdown")
public net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager ehCacheManager() {
     net.sf.ehcache.config.Configuration config = new net.sf.ehcache.config.Configuration();



    CacheConfiguration cacheConfigurationCategories = new CacheConfiguration();
    cacheConfigurationCategories.setName("categories");

    cacheConfigurationCategories.setMemoryStoreEvictionPolicy("LRU");
    cacheConfigurationCategories.setMaxEntriesLocalHeap(100);
    cacheConfigurationCategories.setMaxElementsOnDisk(100);
    config.addCache(cacheConfigurationCategories);

    return net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.newInstance(config);
}

@Bean
@Override
public CacheManager cacheManager() {
    return new EhCacheCacheManager(ehCacheManager());
}

@Bean
@Override
public KeyGenerator keyGenerator() {
    return new SimpleKeyGenerator();
}
```

}

Comment: The code looks ok so either repository.findAll does not return anything or your caching configuration is wrong.

Comment: Hi added my caching config

Answer (score 0):

I have only used it with the configuration in xml which looks like this

```
    @Bean(name = "ehcache")
    public EhCacheManagerFactoryBean ehCacheManagerFactoryBean() {
        EhCacheManagerFactoryBean ehCacheManagerFactoryBean = new EhCacheManagerFactoryBean();
        ehCacheManagerFactoryBean.setConfigLocation(new ClassPathResource("ehcache.xml"));
        return ehCacheManagerFactoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public CacheManager cacheManager() {
        EhCacheCacheManager cacheManager = new EhCacheCacheManager();
        cacheManager.setCacheManager(ehCacheManagerFactoryBean().getObject());
        return cacheManager;
    }
```

with the following xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ehcache xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://ehcache.org/ehcache.xsd">
    <diskStore path="java.io.tmpdir"/>

<cache name="cacheName"
       maxElementsInMemory="1000"
       eternal="false"
       timeToIdleSeconds="28800"
       timeToLiveSeconds="28800"
       overflowToDisk="false"
       maxElementsOnDisk="200"
       diskPersistent="false"
       diskExpiryThreadIntervalSeconds="120"
       memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU"/>             

</ehcache>
```

Comment: can you place your xml please?

Comment: Hard to say what may be wrong. Try to add a key in the cacheable annotation.

Comment: its work for single elements but not for list of objects and i tried key but with no luck

Comment: Dont know what else to do. Turn on logging and try with the simplest possible case.